# Using ASP.NET Impersonation to get the windows login name

Tags: asp.net

I am creating an ASP.NET Web Forms app that it to be accessed only from within the office network. The office network uses Active Directory to authenticate users.

When a request arrives at the server (IIS) and gets passed to ASP.NET, I want to be able to get the windows login name of the user that sent the request. Does ASP.NET Impersonation give me this capability? I think it does, but I don't understand it 100% and am having trouble understanding it.

How does Impersonation actually work? Does it associate the IP address of the incoming request with a machine in the network?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller action you can use `User.Identity.Name`